# How do waves transfer mass?

Tags: waves

A similar question was asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/184592/does-the-statement-waves-only-transfer-energy-not-matter-violate-e-mc2), however the discussion was led astray by involving the equation $E=mc^2$. I know that waves transfer energy, but do they transfer mass? And, if they do, what would be its physical implications?

I tried to think about this question in terms of sound waves: Sound waves are longitudinal pressure waves. The regions of compression and rarefaction are marked by changes in density. But with a change in density, we have an inverse change in the volume so can we argue that the mass in a given volume of the medium remains the same?

Answer (score 4):

In a strict, linear view of the world, waves simply transfer energy through space or media. But the world is almost never linear, and if one looks closer mass will be set in motion or transported with the wave energy. Examples? Ocean surface waves. Although energy is transported across the surface, one can trace local elliptical transport of water molecules. Also vortex rings. Particles can be trapped within the confines of a vortex ring moving through space.